# Parse out spaces in between words in PowerShell

Tags: parsing, powershell, csv

My goal is to eventually generate a CSV file that I can use in PowerShell. I am having troubles with the delimiter aspect of the command though.

[image: data]

My problem is that there are different amounts of white spaces in between the headers. Should I try to edit all the white spaces and replace them with a "," so I can import-csv easily? If so how? Is there another way to convert this to a CSV easily?

At first I tried to replace every space with a "," but it obviously didnt turn out right.. Here's what I have so far.

```
$Data = GC $FileLocation|Select -skip 1|%{
    [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        "Interface"=$_.substring(0,40).Trim()
        "IP-Address"=$_.Substring(41,24).Trim()
        "OK?"=$_.Substring(66,4).Trim()
        "Method"=$_.Substring(70,7).Trim()
        "Status"=$_.Substring(76,35).Trim()
        "Protocol"=$_.Substring(112,($_.length - 111))
    }
}
$data
```

Comment: Those are the exact same substring numbers I have. I told you that you **have** to look at your header line, find out what column each header item starts at, and how many characters to the next header item. I can not know how many characters wide the IP-Address field needs to be. Post your header line in text, not a screen grab, and I can probably help with figuring out columns if you are confused about that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will replace one or multiple instances of white space with one `,`

```powershell
$data = Get-Content $filelocation 
$cleanedUpData = $data -replace "\s+",","
$csv = Convertfrom-Csv $cleanedUpData    
$csv   ## this line will output the resultant csv object
```

Comment: I get this weird error `ConvertFrom-Csv : The member "down" is already present.
At line:11 char:11
+ $newcsv = ConvertFrom-Csv $cleanedUpData`

Comment: You probably have more than one header that's two words and includes the word Down, and since it is replacing any occurrence of ONE or more space as a break, it's breaking up two word headers into two different headers, so `"Break It Down"` becomes `"Break","It","Down"`. To fix that change it to `"\s\s+"` and you should be good to go. **Edit:** Nevermind, that won't work since you have single spaced columns.

Comment: Open up your file and replace all intsances of _administratively down_ with _administrativelydown_, I think that's messing the process up because _administratively down_ is being treated as 2 values. Do `echo $cleanedUpData`, this should give you further clue if above doesn't help.

Comment: I did what TheMadTechnician suggested. Now I get this error: `Convertfrom-Csv : The member "YES NVRAM" is already present.
At line:7 char:8
+ $csv = Convertfrom-Csv $cleanedUpData`

Comment: Here's what $cleanedupDAta looks like printed out -`Interface,IP-Address,OK? Method Status,Protocol,Embedded-Service-Engine0/0 unassigned,YES NVRAM,administratively down down,GigabitEthernet0/0,172.xx.xx.xx,YES NVRAM,up,up,GigabitEthernet0/1,unassigned,YES NVRAM,administratively down down,GigabitEthernet0/2,u
nassigned,YES NVRAM,administratively down down,Serial0/0/0,unassigned,YES NVRAM,up,up,Serial0/0/0.100,152.xxx.xx.xx6,YES NVRAM,up,up,Serial0/1/0,unassigned,YES unset,administratively down down,Loopback0,172.xx.x.x,YES NVRAM,up,up,`

Comment: Try my suggestion from above.

Comment: @Raf One I combined those words it still errors with `Convertfrom-Csv : The member "YES NVRAM" is already present.
At line:7 char:8
+ $csv = Convertfrom-Csv $cleanedUpData`

Comment: @krousemw - try my edited answer, this time it really works. Wonders a long weekend away can do to your brain..

Answer (score 1):

Actually going to go a whole other route with this. Since you know where the columns should be I would suggest pulling substrings and trimming them to get your data. Check this out:

```
$Data = GC $FileLocation|Select -skip 1|%{
    [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        "Interface"=$_.substring(0,40).Trim()
        "IP-Address"=$_.Substring(41,24).Trim()
        "OK?"=$_.Substring(66,4).Trim()
        "Method"=$_.Substring(70,7).Trim()
        "Status"=$_.Substring(76,35).Trim()
        "Protocol"=$_.Substring(112,($_.length - 112))
    }
}
```

Now, **I do not know where the actual columns line up** so you will need to modify the SubString qualifiers for each property listed there. Remember that it is column# (starting at 0, not 1), and then how many characters you want to capture (everything up to the next field, including spaces since it trims those for you). The numbers listed are just some fabricated ones that worked for the test I ran, yours will be different!

Comment: Sorry, I have a sea of red errors but I'm trying to understand this. `Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"` `At line:8 char:5
+     [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Sounds like your last SubString is either missing the parenthesis around `$_.Length - ###` or your number is wrong there. Try reducing that number by 1 or more and see if that comes out ok. Remember that most things are going to be 1 less than you think because you start at character 0, not character 1. **Edit:** If you can update your question with the code you are trying to use it would help.